# In AWS CloudFormation Templates, can I do addition or subtraction on references

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm writing an AWS CloudFormation template, and I would like to define a Parameter with a default value that is two higher than the value passed in for another parameter.  For example, I would like to be able to do something like:

```
MaxPreparedCapacity:
  Type: Number
  Default: !Add:
    - !Ref DesiredCapacity
    - 2
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported out of the box. You can see the duplicate answer linked by Mark B in the comments for more info about possible workarounds.